# Deleting a cookie from an array list

Tags: jquery, cookies

I am not able to figure out how to delete a cookie inside a array?

Basically I have a array where I store all my cookies. Now I am trying to
delete a 'cookie' with a click event but not able to figure out why the cookie list
doesn't get updated?

Perhaps I need to reset the cookie list?

Please advice.

Here is my code for inserting a cookie:

```
var my_array = [];
$(".addCookie a").click(function(e) {       
  var val = $(this).attr("href");                                         
  if (my_array.indexOf(val) == -1) {   my_array.push(val); }   
$.cookie('Cookies', my_array);
e.preventDefault();
return false;       
 });
```

and this for deleting a cookie present inside a array

```
$(".remCookie a").click(function(e) {
    var val = $(this).attr("href");
    var index = my_array.indexOf(val);
    if (index == -1) {
        my_array.splice(index, 1);
    }       
        e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two problems when you remove a cookie; you splice the array if the index *is* equal to -1 (i.e. it the value isn't in the array), and you don't put the array into the cookie.

```
$(".remCookie a").click(function(e) {
  var val = $(this).attr("href");
  var index = my_array.indexOf(val);
  if (index != -1) {
    my_array.splice(index, 1);
    $.cookie('Cookies', my_array);
  }       
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
```

});